# How do I modify links that belongs only to a specific class?

Tags: html, css

I want to modify links ( `<a>` tags ) that only belongs to the class content.

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="content">
        <a href="semI">SEM I </a> </br></br>
        <a href="semII">SEM II </a>
</div>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
a.content:link, a.content:visited {
    background-color: #f44336;
    color: white;
    width : 400px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    text-align: left; 
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yz1gttd1/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your css to `.content a`

```
.content a:link, .content a:visited {
        background-color: #f44336;
        color: white;
        width : 400px;
        padding-left: 25px;
        text-align: left; 
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

Also, `br` tags should be written as `<br>`, not `</br>`

```css
.content a:link,
.content a:visited {
  background-color: #f44336;
  color: white;
  width: 400px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <a href="semI">SEM I </a> 
  <br>
  <br>
  <a href="semII">SEM II </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`a.content:link, a.content:visited` is looking for any links which have a class of `content`, so your HTML would need to change to:

```
<div class="content">
        <a href="semI" class="content">SEM I </a> </br></br>
        <a href="semII" class="content">SEM II </a>
</div>
```

To keep your HTML the same, if you amend the CSS so it's targeting links *within* an ancestor with a class of `content`, you'll be good to go:

```
.content a:link, .content a:visited {
    background-color: #f44336;
    color: white;
    width : 400px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    text-align: left; 
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```